# Why dockerized mongo drops my database periodically?

Tags: mongodb, security, docker, docker-compose, drop-database

I got a little web-service. On the back-end I got dockerized mongo and a few casual stuff like nodejs & nginx. Everything in separate container. And communicates via virtual network.
So my web-service is working few months. And during this time my database has been dropped twice. But I haven't even committed any changes.

Mongo saves data into a volume. So all the data is ok after restarting containers. I checked out the logs, and saw this. But I've no idea why this is happening. Is it some hacker attack?

```
2017-05-10T13:30:31.592+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 178.174.137.79:51802 #120 (4 connections now open)
2017-05-10T13:30:31.719+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] dropDatabase DB_DROPPED starting
2017-05-10T13:30:31.734+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] dropDatabase DB_DROPPED finished
2017-05-10T13:30:31.775+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] dropDatabase hypergraph starting
2017-05-10T13:30:32.196+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] dropDatabase hypergraph finished
2017-05-10T13:30:32.198+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] command hypergraph command: dropDatabase { dropDatabase: 1.0 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:61 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 1, W: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 421ms
2017-05-10T13:30:32.238+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] dropDatabase local starting
2017-05-10T13:30:32.242+0000 I COMMAND  [conn120] dropDatabase local finished
2017-05-10T13:30:32.278+0000 I NETWORK  [conn120] end connection 178.174.137.79:51802 (3 connections now open)
```

Comment: what is `command hypergraph command: dropDatabase`? Who connects from `178.174.137.79:51802`?

Comment: That's what I need to figure out. I've three containers: 172.18.0.2 - mongo
172.18.0.3 - nodejs
172.18.0.4 - nginx.  Those are addresses for virtual network for docker-compose.

Comment: Ok, I've found out that that mongo port has been exposed globally for some reason. I guess I need to block it.
```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1430/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::27017                :::*                    LISTEN      23446/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      17291/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1430/sshd       

```

Comment: either use `docker network create` see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/ or use `docker-compose` (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to have your 3 containers in their own network, the methode with `docker run --link` is now deprecated (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)